# How to configure xrandr to use builtin display as fallback

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr, i3-window-manager

I have an external display at work that I use as my primary display while not using the builtin display of my laptop, e.g.

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --off --output DP2-2 --auto
```

However, when I go away from my desk for more than 10 minutes, the external display will turn itself off. i3wm then automatically logs off, because there is no output available.

Can I tell xrandr to use the builtin display as a fallback in case the external display turns itself off, gets disconnected or becomes unavailable otherwise?

Comment: Which version of i3 are you using? https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/1884

Comment: @TomYan 4.10.3 Thanks for the link. I'll install and test 4.11 today

Comment: @TomYan Wonderful. Problem solved. I'll gladly accept the answer if you post it. I wonder if I should change the title of the question?

Comment: Good to hear. I am not sure if it's necessary to modify the question or write an answer for it though, since it's just a bug of a specific version of i3.